# Segmentation fault in google test

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, googletest, cmake-gui

Segmentation error when using Google tests

test.cpp:

```
#include <interface.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(ParseDelimited, DefaultTest){
    
    EXPECT_EQ(for_test(), 1);
};
```

src/interface.h:

```
int for_test()
{
    return 1;
}
```

tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(Tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Test tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test
    gtest gtest_main
    pthread
    )
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0016 NEW)

project(CCSDS VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Project")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

add_subdirectory(tests)
enable_testing()
```

I can't figure out where there might be a segmentation fault.

I tried to change the functions in the text, tried to run it without using the interface.h but nothing helped

Comment: Could it be the same problem as this very recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77795148 ?

Comment: Have you taken the first step of running this in gdb to see where the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: Yes, it occurs when the "test" starts working

Comment: Does it still happen the same if you comment out the `EXPECT_EQ` so the test is empty? How about if you just call `for_test` directly without the macro wrapper?

Comment: @mikluxa21 I gave this a shot as I did for the question linked in prapins comment (see my comment there) and the result is the same; I am able to build and run your test with no issue. I did misread your directory strucure a bit but with that fixed, I believe I am working with the exact same setup as you. I build with  `cmake -S . -B build` and `cmake --build build`, and then run `./build/tests/Test` to get test passed output.

Comment: That's the problem, everything should work, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @mikluxa21 you may get a little more help if you edit to add info about your gtest version (/how it was installed) and OS/environment. I personally probably won't be able to help much beyond telling you what you already know, but someone who has worked with gtest for more than a day may come by and glean something from that extra info. Personally I'm also curious if you're running a similar setup to the other linked question about gtest segfaulting

Comment: if you have a core dump file, then open in gdb and see the stack trace. It will point to the line where seg fault occurred https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/gdb_core.html